# Working with Informatica

Tags: odbc, sql-server-2012, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am setting up a dev environment for a project, with informatica 9.1 and SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

Installation etc has finished fine and no issues reported so far.

When we are trying to run our first mapping/workflow, the SQL Server database connectivity is becoming a bottleneck.

I tried creating a native connection to SQL Server, and also odbc, both don't seem to work, the session in question just fails to initialize. The error message finally is

> failed to prepare session

Am I missing something here? Any experiences?

Disclaimer: This is my first ever attempt to host Infa repository at SQL Server, and also, using source and target as SQL Server.

Comment: Nope, the session log is not created at all. the workflow log complains about not being able to prepare session :(

Comment: I just went ahead with reimpoting src & tgt objects as well as creating a new intg srvc. Still same msg...

Comment: Can you please tell us how you have configured odbc.ini file for sql server with informatica? also confirm the path in which odbc.ini file is placed?

Comment: Well, its all on windows environment, therefore I didnt had to configure anything in odbc.ini manually. I just created a dsn using the windows odbc gui. And used that in the odbc connection.  btw, the native client is also available on this system, and that too is not working :(

Comment: Have been trying further, and found that no session is being run by the system, even the one thats reading from a flat file and writing to another flat file.. guess something is wrong with my setup of repository/integration service... digging in new direction now...

Comment: Ok guys, looks like its something to do with my repository/integration setup... posting it in a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061423/sql-server-repository-for-informatica-powercenter

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old now but have just come across it and remembered I faced a similar issue with Infa 9 (but with repo hosted on Oracle).

The cause of the "failed to prepare session" error for me was that one or more objects used by the workflow were checked out.  Once everything referenced by the workflow was checked in again, the error went away and the workflow completed successfully.