# SQL Server repository for informatica powercenter

Tags: sql-server-2012, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have a powercenter 9.1 installation on windows server 2008 R2.
The repository is on the same box, hosted on sql server 2012.  I have configured a new user (with sql server authentication) and have the repo db owned by that user. (it has the owner role)

The **core problem** : I am not able to run a simple test workflow on this setup.

Here's what I have been trying

The windows firewall has been taken down now for about an hour or so.

The repository service and integration service are running in trace/debug mode respectively.

The integration service log complains that it cant find a certain session for a certain workflow in certain folder (with ids for all of them).

When I log into sql server mgmt console, and try to query the repository tables for those exact items (since i have the ids from logs), all the data is present...

I fail to understand what is that I am messing up...

Disclaimer - my knowledge of sql server is really low.. may be 1 or 2 on scale of 10, since I have been living on the other side of fence (with oracle) for all of my career...

Comment: Please... anybody.. anything... I am really stuck with this situation..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try keeping the sql server login/user name and the associated default schema name as same?